# Custom error pages with ThoughtBot High Voltage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, high-voltage

I'm using 1.2.2 of High Voltage, on a rails 3.2.2 app, and can't seem to get my app to fire a custom 404 when a page is not found - I just get the "Routing Error, No such page: " error page.

Routes.rb:

```
...

match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'home'

match '/404', :to => 'errors#not_found'
match '/422', :to => 'errors#server_error'
match '/500', :to => 'errors#server_error'

match '/:id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get
```

I have also set the following in application.rb (which I believe is the Rails 3.2 way of kicking off the routing errors):

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

But I still get the default Routing Error page.

I've also tried using this in my app controller:

```
unless config.consider_all_requests_local
        rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_500
        rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
        rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404
        rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_404
        rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_404
    end

    protected

    def render_500 exception
      logger.error exception.inspect
      render :template => "/errors/server_error.html.haml", :status => 500, :layout => 'application'
    end

    def render_404 exception
      logger.error exception.inspect
      render :template => "/errors/not_found.html.haml", :status => 404, :layout => 'application'
    end
```

But it still doesn't work.

I'm stumped! Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you deleted the 404.html and 500.html files in /public?

Comment: I hadn't until you suggested it, but it's still the same...

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to get a custom 404 page working with High Voltage with the following modifications:

Note: if you are testing locally you'll need to run `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` because development mode shows a different 404 error page.

```
# config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

# config/routes.rb
get '/404', to: 'errors#not_found'
```

Then we just need to create an `ErrorsController` and a view for `errors/not_found.html.erb`